# python read csv files with same basename and save as different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have 20 csv files with the same basename and a number from 100 to 2000 with an increment of 100 between files, such that samp_100.csv, samp_200.csv, samp_300.csv, ..., samp_1900.csv, samp_2000.csv.

I am trying to read these files into python. I am trying the following.

```
T = np.arange(100,2100,100)
for i in T: 
    df = pd.read_csv("samp_{i}.csv".format(i=i))
```

Although I do not get an error, the files aren't read in the correct order from 100 to 2000. When I use df.head, I do not see the first lines of the file samp_100.csv. Also the files are concatenated into a single file called df. Is there an equivalent way to achieve this but instead have 20 separate dataframes with the names df_100, df_200, ..., df_1900, df_2000?

Comment: You could put them all in a list e.g. `df_list.append(pd.read_csv("samp_{i}.csv".format(i=i)))`

Comment: I think the issue is when I read the files. The order seems to have changed. I cannot manipulate the dataframe if my 20 files are concatenated in ascending order from 100 to 2000.

Comment: What you're seeing is the data from `samp_2000.csv` because you're overwriting `df` in every pass of the loop. The files will be read in order (just try changing `df = pd.read_csv(...)` to `print(...)` and you'll see).

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for the explanation. So to save all of the files, should I put them in a list as you recommended inside of the loop? Would you mind explaining me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: That would probably be the best solution unless you can completely process them in the loop.

Comment: I tried ```T = np.arange(100,2100,100)
for i in T: 
    df_list = pd.read_csv("samp_{i}.csv".format(i=i))
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv("samp_{i}.csv".format(i=i)))``` I believe now, I am seeing only the data from samp_100.csv. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong here. Thank you

Comment: You should have `df_list = []` *before* the loop, and *only* the `append` in the loop

Comment: Thanks! That does work. I am, however, trying to manipulate the file by columns to find averages. If I have a list containing my 20 files, almost separately, it becomes more difficult to manipulate the whole thing by columns. Is there any way I can still have my data as a dataframe? Perhaps just concatenating the whole thing together

Comment: See the answer someone just posted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [**`pandas.concat`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

Try this :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

T = np.arange(100,2100,100)

list_of_df = []
for i in T:
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(f"samp_{i}.csv")
    list_of_df.append(temp_df)
    
df = pd.concat(list_of_df, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

If you need to add a column with the name of the `.csv`, include the line below after calling [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) inside the loop.

```
temp_df.insert(0, "filename", f"samp_{i}")
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. When I run this all my dataframe values become NaN, but the dimensions are correct.

Comment: I run the code on my machine and I did'nt get `NaN` values. Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: Yes! I wish I could provide a screenshot. When I do df.shape I get 500000 rows × 203 columns. Each one of my files has 25000 rows x 13 columns. So my dimensions should be 500000 rows x 13 rows if concatenated by rows. When I print df, all my cell values become NaN. The column names, however, have numerical value. Please let me know if I can clarify anything else. Thank you!!

Comment: Can you show with a screenshot (in your post) how look like one of your `.csv` files ? Does they have the same columns names ?

Comment: My columns do not have names. I added header=None and I believe this did the trick. I will keep on exploring and update the comments if it is not fully resolved. Thank you!

Comment: You did well by adding the argument `header=None`. Happy coding!